# Xamarin android emulator on Visual Studio 2017 blacked out

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I'm trying my hand at making mobile apps using `C#` and `Xamarin` on Visual Studio 2017. What I'm trying to do is test out the system by making a simple application that has two buttons that either increment or decrements a number by 1 when clicked. Nothing fancy. But when I try to run the android emulator, it is just a black screen. Nothing loads. And when I "x" out of the emulator, I get a `There were deployment errors. Continue?` dialogue box when it's done.

I have searched all over for a solution, and nothing I've tried has worked so far.
Among the things I have tried:

- Enabling virtualization in the BIOS settings.
- Disabling "Use host GPU" in the AVD.
- Change from Debug mode to Release mode.
- Ticked "Wipe User Data" from the launch options.
- Restarts and rebuilds along with "clean Solution" here and there.

I also tried using the `Xamarin` Live Player paired with my phone to no avail.
(Also, I have no `drawable` icon in my `drawable` folder under resources. Is that anything that's necessary??)

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLaW8.jpg

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7.

Comment: Is this error visible in the output window, and if not what does it say in it?

Comment: Any AVD with memory bigger than something like 700 MB has issues on Windows. Set the memory to that level and you should be fine.

Comment: @IvanIčin I tried to, but now I can't edit or create any AVDs. I can't even look at the details, since as soon as I click on the button, the device manager window disappears. And with anything else, the "OK" button is grayed out. Never happened before.

Comment: Alright so I did absolutely nothing and it's working now :/
Still can't create a new AVD thought...

Comment: Go to Tools -> Android -> Android Emulator Manager, then create your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have JDK 9 installed you can try uninstalling it.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/jdk9-errors/#Known_Issues_with_JDK_9

This fixed the problem for me. I had JDK 9 installed and even if in my Xamarin options I was pointing to JDK 8 folder, it was messing up my deployment.